# Migration data from Tridion to Drupal

Tags: migrations

I've been tasked with migrating a Tridion based website to a Drupal installation. (It's more of a rebuild really)

I was wondering if any of you have any experience with migrating the data from Tridion in a such a form that I could use it in Drupal. I have never worked with Tridion and don't know the first thing about it (the documentation does not seem to be open?).

So my question to you is: What is the best/easiest/most reliable way to import the data from a Tridion driven application in to a Drupal application? (I would seriously prefer not to do it manually.)

Any general tips you might have are also much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of api/integration points for SDL Tridion, depending on your version you have:

SDL Tridion 2009 and previous -> TOM (Tridion Object Model) a COM+ API you can use in a .NET project.

SDL Tridion 2011 -> TOM (as before) or the SDL Tridion Core Service (.NET web service)

I'd recommend using these APIs to extract the information you need from Tridion into XML data in the structure that makes it easy for you to work with.

You can then use something like the services module http://drupal.org/project/services to process and import your XML.

Also maybe of use... SDL Tridion is a component based CMS and content is based on a specific **Schema** items.   A schema is likely to translate to a drupal **content type** pretty well, but if you're trying to achieve the sort of flexible layout that you can get from SDL Tridion (page/component templates) you'll likely need to be using the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.. or something similar.

Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! I'll give it a try. I do have some questions though: the site I need to migrate doesn't have a lot of actual written content it's mostly a big list of all sorts of files (pdf's, .doc's) in specific structures. Do you think Drupal will be able to provide a better experience than Tridion? I am not so sure. Also do you know where I could get some information on Tridion? It seems like all of their documentation is locked away. And I'd love to learn more about the data structures.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell about Tridion, but I'm sure there is a database of some sort.

As soon as you're talking about data migration, you have to consider the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

Feeds can eat many data formats, XML and CSV for instance, so it's just a matter of exporting your data in a smart way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out together with the services module to see what works best. I'll be sure to post back when I have more information.